# Dynamic SQL to generate a series of 'LIKE' statements in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dynamic-sql

In Snowflake, I have a table filled with names that I want to exclude from my data set, but some of the names are just email domains so I want to use an ilike statement to exclude them.

I'd like to use a table with parts of names as an exclusion list so that I don't need to maintain a like statement.  For example, if I have the below 2 tables:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TABLE test ( id number, last_name varchar, first_name varchar )
as SELECT * FROM VALUES 
(1, 'Goehan', 'Aylin'),
(2, 'Jacobs', 'Alvin'),
(3, 'Kong', 'Jackie'),
(4, 'Yong', 'Steve'),
(5, 'Joe', 'Black');


CREATE or REPLACE TABLE test_excludes (  excl_last varchar )
as SELECT * FROM VALUES 
('ong'),
('oe');
```

What I'm trying to do is exclude 'Yong', 'Kong', 'Goehan', and 'Joe'.  However, I think if I do some sort of cartesian join that may be inefficient so I'm wondering if it's possible to use dynamic SQL to create the ilike statement using Snowflake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEFT JOIN will suffice:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
LEFT JOIN test_excludes e
  ON t.last_name ILIKE '%' || e.excl_last  -- || '%' -- if anywhere in the string
WHERE e.excl_last IS NULL;
```

Output:

[image]